# How to always get the tip of a raycast?

Tags: mrtk

I was wondering if there is an all in one solution for the target position on an OnPointerDown. I want to spawn things on surfaces and if I don't hit anything, place it where the cursor is. This is not as trivial as I thought, or is it?
In case of the Hololens, listening to OnPointerDown does not contain information about the position of the Default Cursor, which seems to be the only one knowing about it's desired position infront of the user. It also does not contain any information about the FocusProvider which uses the DefaultCursor.
So in the case of a failed pointer hit, on the Hololens, I need to retrieve the default cursor from the FocusProvider via the MixedRealityToolkit.
This is a little weird and feels like the information of the FocusProvider, and/or the cursor should be part of the information.
I know, the OnPointerDown is issued by the hand, but in case of the Hololens 1, who doesn't want to work with the gaze?
Even more strange is the fact, that in case of a hit, the InputEventData does contain a lot of information, which is not even originating from the hand but from the head, which is the FocusProvider, is it not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get the position of the pointer endpoint in OnPointerDown, OnPointerClicked, and OnPointerUp:

```
var result = eventData.Pointer.Result;
if (result != null)
{
    var endPoint = result.Details.Point;
}
```

For example, here is a recent script where I used this to spawn an object wherever I had clicked:

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickSpawn : MonoBehaviour, IMixedRealityPointerHandler
{
    public GameObject spawnObject;
    public InputSourceType sourceType = InputSourceType.Hand;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnEnable()
    {
        MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.Register(gameObject);

    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem != null)
        {
            MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.Unregister(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }

    public void OnPointerDragged(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (spawnObject != null && eventData.InputSource.SourceType == sourceType)
        {
            var spawn = Instantiate(spawnObject);
            var result = eventData.Pointer.Result;
            if (result != null)
            {
                spawn.transform.position = result.Details.Point;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerClicked(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you can get the *direction* the pointer was going at the tip using this:
`var direction = eventData.Pointer.Rays[eventData.Pointer.Result.RayStepIndex].Direction;`